# Can Tor protect me from websites that aim to extract info from my device?

Tags: website

When using Tor, I enable scripts globally.

Can the websites that I visit extract info such as how many hours ahead or behind UTC my device is configured, MAC addresses of my NIC, etc?

My device runs on Ubuntu OS.

Answer (score 0):

[This person asked this question on /r/tor as well](https://www.reddit.com/r/TOR/comments/7hp71q/can_tor_protect_me_from_websites_that_aim_to/).

---

You're talking about Tor Browser. Not Tor.

It does a much better job than any other browser. [A lot of thought](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser/design/) has gone into its security.

In general, I don't think getting a MAC address with JavaScript is even possible.* [First Google result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16556700/how-to-get-client-mac-address-by-using-javascript).

It's trivial to get what time your computer thinks it is with JavaScript. If your browser doesn't lie about (or just omits entirely) your timezone, that's simple too. Since Tor Browser lies about (or omits, idk which) your timezone, websites only learn how inaccurate your clock is when you have JavaScript enabled. They learn nothing with it disabled.

* Exploits don't count. If they did count, then you're screwed because I'd assume the Bad Guy can do just about anything on your computer at that point

Answer (score 0):

If "ALL" the scripts are allowed to be execute on the TOR browser bundle. The website can check your timezone, your OS fingerprint and your browser. They may also check what all websites you are logged in.

If you want to check what all your browser reveals about you. Head to [Hidester](https://hidester.com/browser-fingerprint/).